# JavaScript import() and export() function usage

Tags: javascript

I once read about the import() and export() functions and how they relate to frames and that sort of deprecated practices.  But i'm wondering if there's any practical use case for these functions on the client side.

Has anybody put import() and export() to use in an interesting way on the browser?

Is there a practical usage with say iFrames?

I was looking at the spec and the MDC docs, but there's really very little regarding these function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: As far as I know that's just about XUL programming; it doesn't have anything to do with Javascript on web pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These functions were deprecated back in Netscape 4. They actually only ever worked in Netscape 4.

Comment: Actually they were probably *deprecated* back in Netscape 4.  Though someone may have a time-value-of-source-code economic theory by now.  :-)

Comment: woops. Damned red squigglies.

Comment: I just had an issue with IE8 where `export` was used as part of a i18n property key in the jQuery i18n plugin. It crashed the page loading when using `ddp.i18n.export.failed` as a key. Accoring to MDN the functions were once deprecated but have now returned to be reserved words. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words